# Multi-Variate Gaussian

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, probability-distributions

I have a few questions on the multi-variate gaussian formulation. I have watched many videos and read the wikipedia but don't fully grasp why things are happening.

[image: formula]

In this image we have the general form of a multi-variate distribution.

My first question is about $\Sigma$ if it is the correlation or covariance matrix. I have been seeing different sources refer to it as both and I don't know why as they are different.

My second question is about the form $x^T \Sigma x$ this general form of wrapping a matrix within two x's is not something I understand the WHY of is this because we want x^2? and if that's the case why can we not do $\Sigma x^Tx$? Finally the $|\Sigma|$ is the determinate of $\Sigma$ but in the univariate case it is the standard deviation, is the determinate of $\Sigma$ equal to the standard deviation?

Any help on this intuition would help me a lot, thanks.

Working out k=2 by hand I get:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/harPa.jpg

Comment: I can sympathize with you.  The notation is getting in the way of understanding.  $\Sigma$ is co-variance matrix.

Comment: I suggest you write out exactly what $(x-\mu)^T\Sigma^{-1}(x-\mu)$ looks like for $k=2$ or $k=3$.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution  has k=2 explicitly.

Comment: Thank you, I did k=3 and am not sure if I have the right intuition but I have added my simple thoughts.

Comment: Your note has $\Sigma$.  It should use $\Sigma^{-1}$.  See the example for k=2 in the Wki link.

Comment: Oh I see, do you mean the bivariate case? I thought you meant multiplying it out not simplifying the equation with 2 my bad.

Comment: I have updated my image and understand the first constant but not so clear on how to further simplify the exponent.

Comment: The bivariate case in Wiki is what you should get.  I don't understand your notation.  Also I am weak on matrix manipulation, so I don't know how to handle $\Sigma^{-1}$, other than its definition..  I suggest you get this inverse matrix explicitly first.

Comment: Got ya, thanks for the help!